# Alternative Info reader

Tags: info

I enjoy having choices of $PAGER, e.g.

- more
- less
- most
- ...

Can I enjoy the same choice when reading Info documentation? (i.e. `info tar`)

What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info_%28Unix%29#List_of_Texinfo_readers), which includes the following:

- info
- [pinfo](http://pinfo.sourceforge.net/)
- tkman
- [tkinfo](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/~axel/tkinfo/) (linked page also has a list of info viewers)
- khelpcenter
- emacs

khelpcenter relies on [info2html](http://sourceforge.net/projects/info2html/) which could also be used to enable reading info files with any browser. However, the converted pages lack tons of useful features, like search and access to the index; even if, like me, you find the `info` implementation of those features lacking, they are still better than nothing.

Comment: What's _pathetic_ about the _index_ feature in `info`? IMO, info's _index_ and its very interface (search of the index and toc with completion) is the one feature that makes it superior to any other documentation system (only when the documentation index is well written though).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: OK, maybe pathetic was an overstatement. Although I still prefer the vim documentation system, whose tab completion and search feels much friendlier to me. I edited the answer to make it clear that my distaste is mine and not an objective fact.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the interface of info is the absolute worst I've ever encountered in the field of documentation viewing. It should be intuitive like ``man``, not requiring to read a 1-hour introduction and remembering all kinds of weird shortcuts.